# About deploying the Backup and DR appliance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, backup, vpc

What operations should be performed when deploying a GCP Backup and DR appliance to a new VPC?

We would like to deploy a new appliance to a VPC other than the one we set up when we first set up the Backup and DR environment.

I would appreciate your advice.

[add appliance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3QT5.png)

Click on the red box above and try to deploy a new appliance.

[add appliance datail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keVjl.png)

Next, on the deploy screen of the appliance, I selected the project, selected the region and zone, and checked the subnetwork, but could not see the VPC for the selected project.